# How can I add the new android chips dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-chips

I have a class called Question which contains a String array of tags. I'm trying to show every question in a Recyclerview using Kotlin and every tag in a new chip. These chips will be included inside a ChipGroup.

My question is:

How can I add every tag element of the array into a new Chip?
I'm trying to do this but It's obviously not working.

```
if (tags != null) {
    for (tag in tags) {
        val chip = Chip(itemView.context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your entire code so far? You're not adding the new `Chip` instances to a parent `View` anywhere. It's also half Kotlin and half Java.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can add `Chip`s the same way as any other `ViewGroup` like so:

```
for (index in tags.indices) {
  val chip = Chip(chipGroup.context)
  chip.text= "Item ${tags[index]}"

  // necessary to get single selection working
  chip.isClickable = true
  chip.isCheckable = true
  chipGroup.addView(chip)
}
```

for singleSelection don't forget to add to your chipGroup:

```
chipGroup.isSingleSelection = true
```

or in xml

```
app:singleSelection="true"
```

Comment: @Choletski the question was asked in kotlin so it was answered in kotlin. The same thing can be applied for Java. It should be a very straightforward change

Comment: @kandroidj How to get selected value of dynamic chips

Comment: @kandroidj How to change background color of the chip and stroke color dynamically ?

Answer (score 5):

I always got the following error when trying to create a new Chip:

> IllegalArgumentException: This component requires that you specify a valid android:textAppearance attribute

This could be fixed by instead inflating a custom `R.layout.chip` with the following line:
`android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip"`